# How to solve $q= \frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{b} + \ln{q}+\ln\ln{n}}$

Tags: logarithms, lambert-w

I have come across this equation recently.  All the variables are positive  and real too.

$$q= \frac{\ln{n}}{\ln{b} + \ln{q}+\ln\ln{n}}.$$

Under what conditions can this be solved for $q$?

Comment: There are three variables. Which variable do you want to see this solved for?

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro I added it a bit late. I would like to solve for $q$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $q = e^x$, so that $\ln q = x.$ Also, put $A = \ln{n},$ $B = \ln{b},$ and $C = \ln{\ln{n}}.$ Then your equation takes the form

$$e^x \; = \; \frac{A}{B + x + C}$$

Multiplying both sides by $B + x + C$ gives

$$ e^x \left(B + x + C \right) \; = \; A$$

Now make the variable change $u = B + x + C,$ so that $x = u - B - C.$ Then we get

$$e^{u - B - C} \cdot u \; = \; A$$

Multiplying both sides by $e^{B+C}$ gives

$$e^u \cdot u \; = \; Ae^{B+C}$$

Now we can express the solution in terms of the [Lambert function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function):

$$ u = W\left(Ae^{B+C}\right)$$

Hence, recalling that $u = B + x + C$ and $q = e^x$, we get

$$ B + x + C \; = \; W\left(Ae^{B+C}\right)$$

$$ x \; = \; W\left(Ae^{B+C}\right) \; - \; B - C$$

$$ e^x \;\; = \;\; \exp\left[W\left(Ae^{B+C}\right) - \; B - C \right]$$

$$ q \;\; = \;\; \exp\left[W\left(Ae^{B+C}\right) \; - \; B - C \right]$$

$$ q \;\;  = \;\; \exp\left[W\left(\left(\ln{n}\right)e^{\ln{b} + \ln{\ln{n}}}\right) \; - \; \ln{b} - \ln{\ln{n}} \right]$$

*(a few minutes later)* Using $e^{\ln{b} + \ln{\ln{n}}} \; = \; e^{\ln{b}} \cdot e^{\ln{\ln{n}}} \; = \; b\ln{n},$ we get

$$ q \;\;  = \;\; \exp\left[W\left(b\left(\ln{n}\right)^2\right) \; - \; \ln{b} - \ln{\ln{n}} \right]$$

Comment: Thanks. Can that be simplified as I find it hard to interpret? $e^{\ln{b}} = b$ for example.  If we replace $W$ by $\ln$ it is exactly $\ln{n}$ right?

Comment: I think it is $q=\frac{\ln{n}}{W(b\ln^2{n})}$

Comment: You're right about being able to compress this a little further. I've included the more compressed expression in my answer. However, I'm pretty sure that the appearance of $W$ cannot be replaced with precalculus type functions. In particular, $W$ is not a logarithm function.

Comment: $W(x)$ is approximately $\ln{x} - \ln{\ln{x}}$ I think. At least $W(x) - (\ln{x} - \ln{\ln{x}}) \rightarrow 0$. This gives $q \approx \frac{\ln{n}}{\ln(b\ln^2{n})}$ .